# contentOffset not updated on UICollectionView if scrollToItemAtIndexPath is called inside viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that is used to simulate the new calendar in iOS 7. This collection view is inside a controller that has a selectedDate property. Whenever the selectedDate property is set the collection view should scroll to the date in the collection view.

The calendar controller's viewWillAppear also ensure the selected date is visible because this controller is cached and reused.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.calendarView scrollToDate:[self selectedDate] animated:NO];
}
```

The problem is that the VERY first time the calendar controller is shown the scroll does not work. The contentOffset of the collection view is not updated.

My current workaround is to schedule the scroll to occur on the next run loop using

```
dispatch_after(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
{
        // Scroll to the date.
    });
```

It looks like when the UICollectionView is not in a window you cannot scroll. Scheduling the scroll to happen on the next run loop ensure that the view has been added to the window and can be properly scrolled.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and what their workarounds?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue (ironically, after building a similar calendar control). My solution so far has been to animate the scroll during `viewDidAppear:`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using auto layout, the issue may be that the constraints haven't set the frames yet. Try calling the scrollToDate: method in viewDidLayoutSubviews (without dispatch_after).

```
@interface CustomViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isFirstTimeViewDidLayoutSubviews; // variable name could be re-factored

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end

@implementation CustomViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.isFirstTimeViewDidLayoutSubviews = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    // only after layoutSubviews executes for subviews, do constraints and frames agree (WWDC 2012 video "Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout")

    if (self.isFirstTimeViewDidLayoutSubviews) {

        // execute geometry-related code...

        // good place to set scroll view's content offset, if its subviews are added dynamically (in code)

        self.isFirstTimeViewDidLayoutSubviews = NO;
    }
```

Comment: This will cause a problem if the user has scrolled away from the selected date and then viewDidLayoutSubviews got triggered. The user could be in the process of scrolling and then all of a sudden get scrolled back to the selected date. In theory you could track some sort of flag so that it is only called once but that feels like more of a hack then a fix.

Comment: @ReidMain When using auto layout, I often set flags in my own code in order to execute geometry-related code the first time the view controller loads. I agree that it doesn't seem ideal; I would rather execute that code in viewDidLoad because it only gets called the first time the view controller loads. However, when working with auto layout, viewDidLoad is way too early to execute geometry-related code (actually, viewDidLoad is often too early even when not using auto layout). Let us know if you find a better solution.

Comment: That makes complete sense. Would you like to update your answer with that caveat and some sample code? I would happily upvote that answer and if no one produces a better one within a few weeks I will accept it.

Answer (score 24):

you can always force auto-layout to layout.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath......
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the best solution so far

Answer (score 3):

**bilobatum**'s answer is correct!
I'm writing this because I don't have reputation to comment... :/

I tried **bilobatum**'s answer in my project, and it worked perfectly!
My code:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    if (currentOffset.y != 999) {
        [collectionView setContentOffset:currentOffset animated:NO];
    }
}
```

currentOsset is a `CGPoint` initialized with x = 0 and y = 999 values (`CGPoint currentOffset = {0,999};`)

In the `viewWillDisappear` method I save the collectionView's contentOffset in the currentOffset.
This way if I navigate to the controller that has the collectionView and I navigated to there before, I will always have the last position.

The code that will work for you:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.calendarView scrollToDate:[self selectedDate] animated:NO];
}
```

Thank you **bilobatum** for the answer!

Comment: You will have issues if viewDidLayoutSubviews is called when your user is scrolling. They could have scrolled away from the current offset and then they would all of a sudden have been scrolled back to it.

Answer (score 0):

Using -viewDidLayoutSubviews created an infinite loop that made the solution too complicated. 
Instead I just added a small delay to let the constraints be created before the scrolling:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ([self.scheduleDate isThisWeek]) [self.calendarLayout performSelector:@selector(scrollToCurrentTime) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```